# How to hide div with text inside if loop returns no posts?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html, echo

First loop retrieves posts related to current post based the primary tag. The second loop, which is displayed below, gets posts based on the secondary tag. If a post is displayed by the first loop it is excluded from being retrieved by the second loop so that there are no duplicate posts.

If there are no posts matching the current post by tag, nothing is shown. Here is where I have a problem. I need the extra `<div id="relatedheader">` element inside (or outside) of the `<ul>` to display the header text "Related posts" (with some style applied like background color). If there are no posts matching it doesn't display but at the moment it returns the header "Related posts" for every post retrieved by the query. I can see that it is echoed out for every post displayed at the moment. I can't see how I can alter the code to make it show only once above the posts?

```
<ul id="related">       
<?php
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
  $first_tag = $tags[1]->term_id;
  $args=array(
    'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'showposts'=>3, //Display this number of related posts
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
   );
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); if (!in_array($post->ID, $ids)) {; echo '<div id="relatedheader">Related posts</div>'; ?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
      <?php } endwhile;
  }
}
?></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your logic from your presentation.  Move all your code that gathers posts and related posts to the top, or to a different file or function, and store the data in an array.  Then, when you get to the part where you output your HTML, you already know whether there are related posts, and you can use an if condition to decide whether to output the header.

Comment: Thank you. Your advice is helpful. I cleaned out all the html and replaced it with `$idspost [] = $post->ID` which stores the ID's. I have checked with `<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($idspost); echo "</pre>"; ?>` and the correct ID's are written on the page. I have spent a lot of time, however, trying to figure out how to pass the info on to the if condition, but my skills are very basic. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: :) I messed up the original comment and replaced it

Comment: Here is the change to the original code: `while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); if (!in_array($post->ID, $ids)) {; $idspost [] = $post->ID; ?>
<?php } $ids[]= $post->ID; endwhile;
  }
}
?>`

Comment: Your code gets a little hard to read with mixed use of new `{ }` and old `while: endwhile;` syntaxes and under-use of newlines.  Try reformatting it to use all `{ }` blocks and put each statement on its own line to make it easier for you, and others, to read and understand.

Comment: I can see that. I would really have to post the whole original code with the changes as above, but it's not possible by adding a comment. I would need to answer my own question to present the code in a readable manner and I guess that is not appropriate since I am still looking for an answer. Perhaps I should ask a new and more specific question in a new thread?

Comment: As suggested, this was indeed solved by storing the data in a new array, after the logic and presentation was separated. Good advice by Umbrella. Thanks again. `<?php
  if(count($relatedpostids)){
    echo "<div>Related posts<ul>";
    foreach($relatedpostids as $id){
       echo '<li>Do stuff...</li>';
    }
    echo "</ul></div>";
  }
?>`